# Refer to an Excel worksheet by Codename in EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am learning to use EPPlus for my C# projects.  I would like to be able to identify a worksheet by its immutable "Codename" rather than the user editable "Name" property.  I do this all the time in VBA.  So here is the code I am trying to implement:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

namespace ARTIST.Infrastructure.Excel;

public class InputFile : IDisposable
{
  private readonly ExcelPackage package;
  private const string defaultFileName = @"C:\Users\Jeff\source\repos\ARTIST\..."; // Full path hidden here.

  public InputFile(ExcelPackage package)
  {
    this.package = package;
  }

  public ExcelWorkbook OpenWorkbook(string filename = defaultFileName)
  {
    return package.Workbook;
  }

  public ExcelWorksheet SelectWorksheet(ExcelWorkbook workbook, string codeName)
  {
    return workbook.Worksheets.Where(w => w.Name == codeName).First();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    package?.Dispose();
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }
}
```

As you can see the lambda expression, the worksheet is only exposing its Name property, but I really want to search for its Codename.  Is this possible in EPPlus?  Thank you for your help.